# Print output of loop in dictionary format

Tags: python, dictionary, printing

My program queries a database and returns all birthdays that are today, tomorrow and upcoming. I would however like the birthdays that are upcoming to be on one line instead of several lines. This is how it looks:
The birthdays are on separate lines:

[image: 1]

This is my code:

```
def in_a_week():
    coming_up = datetime.now()

    with open('bDay_db.json')as read_file:
        bdays = json.load(read_file)

    for x in range(2, 5):
        soon = (coming_up + timedelta(days=x))
        upcoming = (soon.strftime('%b %d'))
        #pprint.pprint(upcoming)

   

        if upcoming in bdays.values():
            print()
            print("Birthday match found in next couple of days: ")
            print()
            print([kv for kv in bdays.items() if kv[1] in upcoming])
            print()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def in_a_week():
    coming_up = datetime.now()

    with open('bDay_db.json')as read_file:
        bdays = json.load(read_file)

    for x in range(2, 5):
        soon = (coming_up + timedelta(days=x))
        upcoming = (soon.strftime('%b %d'))
        #pprint.pprint(upcoming)

   
        print("Birthday match found in next couple of days: ")
        if upcoming in bdays.values():
            print([kv for kv in bdays.items() if kv[1] in upcoming], end = ", ")
        print()
```

This should work!

**What was the problem?**
As you said you wanted the dates on the same line. So, first of all, you were using print statements, which adds a newline to the output. Also, the `Birthday match found in next couple of days:`statement was inside the loop. That should print only at the beginning, right?

**what was the fix?**
I removed the print statements first. Then the `end=", "` makes sure that after a print statement, your next output remains in the same line. Here, for added functionality, I put a comma inside, so it looks pretty. Also, as I already mentioned the `Birthday match found in next couple of days:` was put outside of the loop. In the end, I put a blank print statement, which makes sure that your output goes on a new line, once you are out of the loop.

Comment: A good answer should explain what the problem was and what you did to solve it ;)

Comment: @edusanketdk unfortunately that doesn't change much, so the output I'm looking for is something like this : 
Birthday found in next couple of days
[('shrek': 'Apr 27')], ['Fiona':'Apr 28)]...

Comment: Hey, just put end=" " in the print statement where you are printing 'Birthday found in next couple of days'. Just like there is one in the print statement inside the loop.